# Declaring parameter when passing to a Function in VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

we have something like this in C#:

```
public static int ToInt<T>(this T obj) =>
       int.TryParse(obj,out int result)?result: -1;
```

we can declared `result` when we passing that to `TryParse` method, is there an equivalent way in vb.NET?

Comment: `VB.Net` doesn't have the Auto-out (inline variable declaration), yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline declarations came to C# with the Version 7.0. VB.NET 15 has been released around the same time.

According to [this](https://www.codeguru.com/columns/vb/whats-new-in-visual-basic-15.html) blog post, inline declarations did not make it to VB.NET 15. (See the section *Language Features that Were Left Out of Visual Basic 15*)

**EDIT**

Apparently VB.NET does not even have the `out` paramter modifier at all. The closest equivalent would be `ByRef`, which is really more like C#s `ref`, which does not support inline declarations, too.

Comment: Although VB doesn't have `out`, if you are writing a VB module to be consumed by C#, you can add the corresponding attribute to the `ByRef` parameter so that C# sees the parameter as `out`.

Answer (score 2):

you may try:

```
            Dim result As Integer = If(Integer.TryParse(obj, result), result, -1)
            Return result
```